# ContentView content width and height -1 when ContentView is well sized

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a simple `Xamarin.Forms` project with a `ContentView` that I'd like to add to a `ContentPage`

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NamespaceX.Xamarin.Target" 
             BackgroundColor="Red">
<ContentView.Content>
    <Button Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
            x:Name="ButtonName"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Here is my `ContentPage`

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NamespaceX.Xamarin"
             x:Class="NamespaceX.Xamarin.MainPage">
    <local:Target></local:Target>
</ContentPage>
```

The `ContentView` is indeed added to the `ContentPage` as the `ContentPage` turns red but no content is displayed.
When I add a `SizeChanged` event listener in the `ContentView`

```cs
private void View_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(this.Width);
    Debug.WriteLine(this.Height);
    Debug.WriteLine(this.Content.Width);
    Debug.WriteLine(this.Content.Height);
}
```

The width and height of the `ContentView` are indeed set `Width: 360`, `Height: 616` but the Content width and height are `-1`.

**EDIT**

I just noticed it was not working using the Xamarin Live Player but was working with the emulator...

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza nothing is hard typed, just retrieved those values when the ContentView fitted my phone

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KujaR.png). Any relevant information was omitted?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza can you show me how your .projitems looks like ?

Comment: I don't have a `.projitems` file.